# Error de importación raro cuando la importación está correcta de programa de Cálculo con PyQt6: name 'Ui_MainWindow' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt6

Este código define una interfaz gráfica de usuario para calcular el valor de una función matemática y el límite de una expresión matemática.
Primero, se define la función *calcular_funcion* que toma una cadena de texto que representa el nombre de una función y un número que representa
el valor de *x*, y devuelve el valor de la función evaluada en ese punto.

Luego, se define la clase *FunctionCalculator* que hereda de *QMainWindow* y define varios elementos de la interfaz de usuario, como etiquetas, campos de entrada y botones.

Los elementos de la interfaz permiten al usuario seleccionar una función, ingresar un valor para *x* y calcular el valor de la función correspondiente.

También permiten al usuario ingresar una expresión matemática que representa un límite y calcular el valor del límite.

Cuando el usuario hace clic en el botón "Calcular función" o "Calcular límite", se llaman a los métodos *calculate_function* y *calculate_limit*, respectivamente, que realizan las operaciones de cálculo correspondientes y muestran el resultado en la interfaz de usuario mediante etiquetas.

El código también importa el módulo *math* para realizar cálculos matemáticos y la biblioteca *matplotlib* para representar gráficamente las funciones y límites.

El error es:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Python\PyQt6\CalculadoradeFuncionesyLimites.py", line 133, in 
> class CalculadoraFunciones(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
> NameError: name 'Ui_MainWindow' is not defined

```
   import math
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from typing import Tuple
   from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
   from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, 
   QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, 
   QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, 
   QPushButton, QComboBox



     def calculate_function(function: str, x: float) -> float:
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "lineal", la función retorna 2x+3.
    if function == "lineal":
        return 2 * x + 3
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "parabolica", la función retorna x^2+5x+2.
    elif function == "parabolica":
        return x ** 2 + 5 * x + 2
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "trigonometrica", la función retorna el seno de "x".
    elif function == "trigonometrica":
        return math.sin(x)
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "logaritmica", la función retorna el logaritmo natural de "x".
    elif function == "logaritmica":
        return math.log(x)
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "normal", la función retorna la función de densidad de probabilidad normal evaluada en "x".
    elif function == "normal":
        return (1 / (2 * math.pi) ** 0.5) * math.exp(-0.5 * x ** 2)
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "neperiana", la función retorna la exponencial de "x".
    elif function == "neperiana":
        return math.exp(x)
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "raiz_enesima", la función solicita al usuario que ingrese un valor entero "n" y luego retorna la raíz "n"-ésima de "x".
    elif function == "raiz_enesima":
        n = int(input("Ingrese el valor de n: "))
        return x ** (1 / n)
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "raiz_cuadrada", la función retorna la raíz cuadrada de "x".
    elif function == "raiz_cuadrada":
        return math.sqrt(x)
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "exponencial_normal", la función retorna la función de densidad de probabilidad exponencial normal evaluada en "x".
    elif function == "exponencial_normal":
        return (1 / (2 * math.pi) ** 0.5) * math.exp(-0.5 * x ** 2) * math.exp(x)
    
    # Si "function" es igual a "neperiana_normal", la función retorna la función de densidad de probabilidad neperiana normal evaluada en "x".
    elif function == "neperiana_normal":
        return (1 / (2 * math.pi) ** 0.5) * math.exp(-0.5 * x ** 2) * math.exp(x)
    
    # Si "function" no coincide con ninguna de las funciones anteriores, la función eleva una excepción.
    else:
        raise ValueError("Función no válida.")

     #La siguiente línea crea una ventana principal de la aplicación
     class FunctionCalculator(QMainWindow):

    #El método "__init__" se ejecuta al iniciar la aplicación
    
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("FuncLimitCalc")

        # Se crea un QLabel para la selección de la función
        self.label_function = QLabel(self)
        self.label_function.setText("Seleccione la función:")
        self.label_function.setGeometry(10, 10, 150, 30)

        # Se crea un QComboBox para la selección de la función
        self.combo_function = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_function.setGeometry(160, 10, 150, 30)
        self.combo_function.addItems(["lineal", "parabolica", "trigonometrica", "logaritmica",
                                      "normal", "neperiana", "raiz_enesima", "raiz_cuadrada",
                                      "exponencial_normal", "neperiana_normal"])

        #Se crea un QLabel para la entrada de x
        self.label_x = QLabel(self)
        self.label_x.setText("Ingrese el valor de x:")
        self.label_x.setGeometry(10, 50, 150, 30)

        # Se crea un QLineEdit para la entrada de x
        self.input_x = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input_x.setGeometry(160, 50, 150, 30)

        #Se crea un QPushButton para calcular la función
        self.button_calcular_funcion = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_calcular_funcion.setText("Calcular función")
        self.button_calcular_funcion.setGeometry(10, 90, 150, 30)
        self.button_calcular_funcion.clicked.connect(self.calculate_function)

        #Se crea un QLabel para el resultado de la función
        self.label_resultado_funcion = QLabel(self)
        self.label_resultado_funcion.setGeometry(10, 130, 300, 30)

        #Se crea un QLabel para la entrada del límite
        self.label_limite = QLabel(self)
        self.label_limite.setText("Ingrese la expresión matemática que representa el límite:")
        self.label_limite.setGeometry(10, 170, 300, 30)

        #Se crea un QLineEdit para la entrada del límite
        self.input_limite = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input_limite.setGeometry(10, 210, 300, 30)

        #Se crea un QPushButton para calcular el límite
        self.button_calcular_limite = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_calcular_limite.setText("Calcular límite")
        self.button_calcular_limite.setGeometry(10, 250, 150, 30)
        self.button_calcular_limite.clicked.connect(self.calculate_limit)

        #Se crea un QLabel para el resultado del límite
        self.label_resultado_limite = QLabel(self)
        self.label_resultado_limite.setGeometry(10, 290, 300, 30)

     #Definición de la clase CalculadoraFunciones que hereda de QMainWindow y de la interfaz gráfica Ui_MainWindow
     class CalculadoraFunciones(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
        #Constructor de la clase
      def __init__(self):
        #Llamada al constructor de la clase QMainWindow
        super().__init__()
        #Llamada al método de inicialización de la interfaz gráfica
        self.setupUi(self)
        #Conexión del botón btn_calcular_funcion con el método calculate_function
        self.btn_calcular_funcion.clicked.connect(self.calculate_function)
         #Conexión del botón btn_calcular_limite con el método calculate_limit

        self.btn_calcular_limite.clicked.connect(self.calculate_limit)

    #Método para calcular el valor de una función en un punto
    def calculate_function(self):
        #Obtención del texto seleccionado en el ComboBox combo_function
        function = self.combo_function.currentText()
         #Obtención del valor numérico ingresado en el QLineEdit input_x
        x = float(self.input_x.text())
        #Cálculo del resultado de la función
        result = calculate_function(function, x)
        #Actualización del texto del QLabel label_resultado_funcion
        self.label_resultado_funcion.setText(f"El resultado es: {result}")

       #Método para calcular el límite de una función en un punto
    def calculate_limit(self, expression, x):
        try:
            #Cálculo del límite de la expresión dada en el punto x/10
            result = limit_calculator(expression, x/10)
            #Actualización del texto del QLabel label_resultado_limite
            self.label_resultado_limite.setText(f"El resultado es: {result}")
        except ValueError as e:
            #En caso de error, se muestra el mensaje de error en el QLabel label_resultado_limite
            self.label_resultado_limite.setText(str(e))


     #Creación de un objeto de la clase CalculadoraFunciones
     calculadora = CalculadoraFunciones()
     #Obtención de la expresión del límite a calcular
     expression = input("Introduce la expresión del límite: ")
     #Generación de los valores de x para graficar el límite
     x_values = list(range(-100, 100))
     #Evaluación de la expresión del límite en los valores de x generados
     y_values = [calculadora.calculate_limit(expression, x/10) for x in x_values]
     #Graficación de la función
     plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
     #Agregado de las líneas x=0 e y=0
     plt.axhline(y=0, color='k')
     plt.axvline(x=0, color='k')
     #Agregado de etiquetas al gráfico
     plt.xlabel('x')
     plt.ylabel('f(x)')
     plt.title('Límite')
     #Mostrado del gráfico generado
     plt.show()
```

Comment: ¿Está bien identado tu código?

Comment: Si , sino me indicara que en x linea hay error de indetacion, pero no entiendo porque dice error de importacion si al principio del codigo si esta importado el modulo

Comment: Me refiero a si está bien identado tu código _en la pregunta_. De no ser así, corrígela.

Comment: Hola Osmer, no, no tienes importado el modulo **Ui_MainWindow**, como no se de donde sale, me tiro a la pileta y digo: tal vez debas poner **class CalculadoraFunciones( QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QtWidgets.Ui_MainWindow ):**